# Python sort JSON file with lots of arrays by name

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have a JSON file that looks like this with one element:

```json
[
    {
        "test1": [
            {
                "checked": [
                    "True"
                ],
                "description": [
                    "asdasd"
                ],
                "fileName": [
                    "GT-002"
                ],
                "imgLoc": [
                    "/Images/GT-002.png"
                ],
                "material": [
                    6
                ],
                "quantity": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need some way to sort my large JSON file by `fileName`. Right now it does it all weird and random and nothing works for me.

`test1` and `test` have the same amount of items, but `NON_BATCH` for example has alot more, and I can't find any way to sort them properly when they are separated.

I have tried the following code:

```py
import json

Data_JSON = 'data.json'
BATCH_NAME = 'NON_BATCH'

with open(Data_JSON) as file:
    Data_JSON_Contents = json.load(file)
    sortedList = sorted(Data_JSON_Contents, key=lambda i: i[BATCH_NAME][0]['fileName'])
    with open(Data_JSON, mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(sortedList, file, ensure_ascii=True, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

If anyone knows any tools or libraries or the proper way to do this, I would really apprciate it, I have tried things with `natsort` such as:

```py
from natsort import natsort_keygen
natsort_key = natsort_keygen()
Data_JSON_Contents[0][BATCH_NAME][0].sort(key=natsort_key)
```

Or something along those lines, but nothing worked for me.

`data.json`

```json
[{"NON_BATCH": [{"checked": ["True"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-003"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-003.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["False"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-005"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-005.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["True"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-013"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-013.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["False"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-006"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-006.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["True"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-007"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-007.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["False"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-012"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-012.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["True"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-009"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-009.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["False"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-004"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-004.png"], "material": [0], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["True"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-008"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-008.png"], "material": [9], "quantity": [1]}, {"checked": ["False"], "description": [""], "fileName": ["GT-010"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-010.png"], "material": [6], "quantity": [1]}], "test": [{"checked": ["False"], "description": ["asdsad"], "fileName": ["GT-001"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-001.png"], "material": [11], "quantity": [1]}], "test1": [{"checked": ["True"], "description": ["asdasd"], "fileName": ["GT-002"], "imgLoc": ["/Images/GT-002.png"], "material": [6], "quantity": [1]}]}]
```

Comment: Why are you using natsort? The data shown here does not appear to call for natural sorting.

Comment: I figured I would try it to see if I 'could' use it, im not using it. I just tried to.

Comment: Ok, just fyi your input data is already sorted.

Comment: My data is not sorted by `fileName`, for example, in `NON_BATCH` the 3rd element ('GT-013') should be at the end of that section. Not near the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stitch together a solution by merging everything into a tuple and then sorting that with `natsort`, and then "stitch" it back together.

Here's the code:

```py
import json
from natsort import natsort_keygen
natsort_key = natsort_keygen()

Data_JSON = 'data.json'
BATCH_NAME = 'NON_BATCH'

file_names = []
image_locations = []
quantities = []
description = []
checkmarked = []
materials = []

def merge(*args):
    return [(args[0][i], args[1][i], args[2][i], args[3][i], args[4][i], args[5][i]) for i in range(len(args[0]))]

with open(Data_JSON) as file:
    Data_JSON_Contents = json.load(file)

    for item in Data_JSON_Contents[0][BATCH_NAME]:
        file_names.append(item['fileName'][0])
        image_locations.append(item['imgLoc'][0])
        quantities.append(item['quantity'][0])
        description.append(item['description'][0])
        checkmarked.append(item['checked'][0])
        materials.append(item['material'][0])

    merged = sorted(merge(file_names, image_locations, quantities,
                          description, checkmarked, materials), key=natsort_key)

    for i, j in enumerate(file_names):
        Data_JSON_Contents[0][BATCH_NAME].pop(0)
        Data_JSON_Contents[0][BATCH_NAME].append({
            'fileName': [merged[i][0]],
            'imgLoc': [merged[i][1]],
            'quantity': [int(merged[i][2])],
            'description': [merged[i][3]],
            'checked': [merged[i][4]],
            'material': [merged[i][5]]
        })
    with open(Data_JSON, mode='w+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(Data_JSON_Contents, file,
                  ensure_ascii=True, indent=4)
```

It's not neat code by any means or optimised, but it works, and if anyone has some suggestions on make this better and alot more 'sleek' i'd be super happy to use it.